# Is there a symbols level option/solution for SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is it possible to have an sld blend the symbology in the lines together just as QGIS and ArcGIS allow using symbol levels?

In QGIS I can use symbol levels on the line layer and have this appearance:

[image]

currently in sld it has this appearance:
[image]

I was hoping to have the appearance of the individual lines blending together as one. The intent is to apply the sld to a geoserver layer. Currently I am only using rules like the one listed below.

```
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffe14c</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

Answer (score 6):

When stacked symbols are only separated by the `<Rule>` tags, the order in which they appear on the map is random. You need to separate them using `<FeatureTypeStyle>` tags. Symbols at the top of the SLD will be drawn first, so for your road example you should put the road casing first followed by the road fill. E.g.

```
<FeatureTypeStyle>
 <Rule>
 <Name>Road casing</Name>
  <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
  <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <LineSymbolizer>
    <Stroke>
      <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>
  </LineSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>

<FeatureTypeStyle>
 <Rule>
 <Name>Road fill</Name>
  <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
  <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <LineSymbolizer>
    <Stroke>
      <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffe14c</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>
  </LineSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Check out our Ordnance Survey SLD's for some [examples](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/styled-layer-descriptors.html)

They can get quite long and complex with multiple rules!

Answer (score 4):

Well that was easy...My issue was I had my line and casing grouped in the FeatureTypeStyle.

The fix was to group the rules for the road in one FeatureTypeStyle and the casing in another. See below:

```
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>50000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>140000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>12500</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>50000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">8</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">11</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">14</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
  <!-- end of motorway casing -->
  <!-- start of motorway -->
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>6500000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>25000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#73452e</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>3000000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>6500000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#d96d6d</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>1500000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>3000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#d94c4c</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>750000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>1500000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#d94c4c</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>50000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>750000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#e55050</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>12500</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>50000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#e55050</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#e55050</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">7</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#e55050</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
    <!-- end of motorway -->
    <!-- start of motorway centerline -->
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>1500000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>3000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#fae57d</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>750000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>1500000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#fae57d</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.5</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>50000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>750000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffe14c</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>12500</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>50000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffe14c</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffe14c</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffe14c</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
  <!-- end of motorway -->
```

Comment: I really liked your output. Amazing roads on zoom level

Answer (score 1):

Just change the 'strike-linecap' of casing lines to 'butt' in order to disappear them at the start and end of line segments as follow:

```
<FeatureTypeStyle>
 <Rule>
 <Name>Casing</Name>
  <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
  <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <LineSymbolizer>
    <Stroke>
      <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">butt</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>
  </LineSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>

<FeatureTypeStyle>
 <Rule>
 <Name>Fill</Name>
  <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
  <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <LineSymbolizer>
    <Stroke>
      <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffe14c</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>
  </LineSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>
```