# Ordering symbols in GeoServer using SLD with rendering transformations

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have been following this post-[Is there a symbols level option/solution for SLD?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113115/is-there-a-symbols-level-option-solution-for-sld) about stacking symbols but I have been stuck in using `<FeatureTypeStyle>` with GeoServer rendering transformations.

I have tried the following but it doesn't even validate in GeoServer

```
<NamedLayer>
<Name>location_site</Name>
<UserStyle>
<!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
  <Title>Stacked Point for location</Title>
  <Abstract>Styles volcanoes using stacked points</Abstract>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Transformation>
      <ogc:Function name="vec:PointStacker">
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>cellSize</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
    </Transformation>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>1 Site</Name>
      <Title>1 site</Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
         <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>1800000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#238f1c</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Mark>
          <Size>8</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>1-100 sites</Name>
      <Title>1-100 sites</Title>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#e8e251</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Mark>
          <Size>12</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>100-500</Name>
      <Title>100-500 sites</Title>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>500</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#bd9524</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Mark>
          <Size>25</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>

    </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>

</UserStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

The PointerStacker is implementing a "point clustering" transformation, has nothing to do with drawing order.

Feature drawing order is controlled by FeatureTypeStyle and the z-ordering vendor options instead, see also:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/z-order/index.html

Comment: I know what the point clustering transformation does. What I am asking is how to include symbols levels in an SLD including transformations

Comment: I don't understand what you mean then, I'd suggest to clarify your question adding an example of what you'd like to get as a result.