# Joining lines with SLD style in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, merge, sld

I want to create a sld style in road lines in qgis. the style has a fill and a border symbology. Everything is ok in qgis but i have an issue with the style in geoserver.  The lines do not merge at the joins. How do i join lines with sld style? **I use the sld for three layers in geoserver (I have three layers in a group layer)**. The other solutions like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113115/is-there-a-symbols-level-option-solution-for-sld) work for just one layer with filtering.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>test</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>test</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">14</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">11</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

[image]

I tested it with just one layer and faced the same problem.