# Problem with Symbol Line Level in GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, style, sld

I created two style for casing and fill for roads layer, but I do not know how to fix symbol level in GeoServer. I followed this answer and the problem still exists [symbol level](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113115/is-there-a-symbols-level-option-solution-for-sld)

[image: symbol level -geoserver]

SLD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Roads Line copy</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Roads Line copy</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Extressway</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Extressway</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Extressway</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>5001</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#e892a2</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5.66929999999999978</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Main Roads</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Main Roads</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Main Roads</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>5001</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#f9b29c</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Main Streets</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Main Streets</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>Main Roads</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>Main Streets</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>5001</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#fbd5a4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Collector Streets</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Collector Streets</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Collector Streets</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>5001</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#f6f9be</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Tertiary Streets</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Tertiary Streets</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Tertiary Streets</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>5001</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Tunnels</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Tunnels</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Tunnels</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>5001</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#e892a2</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Tunnels</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Tunnels</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Tunnels</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>2500</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>5000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#e892a2</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">25</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Extressway</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Extressway</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Extressway</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>2500</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>5000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#e892a2</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">28</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Main Roads</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Main Roads</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Main Roads</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>2500</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>5000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#f9b29c</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">25</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Main Streets</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Main Streets</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Main Streets</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>2500</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>5000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#fbd5a4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">21</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Collector Streets</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Collector Streets</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Collector Streets</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>2500</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>5000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#f6f9be</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">21</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Tertiary Streets</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Tertiary Streets</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type_ar</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Tertiary Streets</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>2500</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>5000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">18</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: without seeing the actual SLD it is impossible to tell what is going on. Most likely is you are drawing them in the wrong order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing your feature types in the wrong order - GeoServer starts at the first `FeatureTypeStyle` and draws all of that and then draws the 2nd, 3rd etc in order.

So you want to draw the "smallest" roads first and then draw the major ones over the top of them.

Comment: I rearranged it, but unfortunately the problem still exist

Comment: then update your question to demonstrate the new issue

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now fine, I rearranged it and I added <FeatureTypeStyle> for each road type